# JMeter Logger (jmeter.log) - How to Change the Timestamp Format (jmeter 5.2.1)

Tags: logging, jmeter, timestamp, format

Currently, the jmeter.log file is written with a timestamp of format 2020-02-13 16:36:29,356

However, the comma before the ms is causing me some issues when parsing in elastic search. I would like to change it to a '.' so that I can use commas to delimit the subsequent log message elements. I tried using pipes, but my devops tell me this is a pain for them...

I've done a fair bit of trawling through the internet and cannot find anything that explains how to modify the jmeter.log timestamp format. Plenty that explains how to change all the other log timestamp formats (e.g. jtl) but nothing on jmeter.log

I saw something that recommended entering log_format=%{time:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss},%5.5{priority},%{category}:,%{message} %{throwable} into jmeter.properties but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm using jmeter 5.2.1

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1. In the *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) locate the following lines:

   ```
   <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
   ```

   and change them to

   ```
   <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
   ```

   So the whole [Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) section would look like:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
     <PatternLayout>
       <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
     </PatternLayout>
   </File>

   <GuiLogEvent name="gui-log-event">
     <PatternLayout>
       <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
     </PatternLayout>
   </GuiLogEvent>
   ```

   2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
   3. That's it, now you should be able to enjoy the dot between seconds and milliseconds

References:

- [Log4J PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Comment: Hey @dimitri T thankyou! Sorry for the slow response...